# PHP Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in search.php

Tags: php

I have a php search file that searches a directory for files with the submitted names and displays the results. I want to use the html form in the same file as the php code i.e., in search.php only like this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get"><input name="q"
type="text"> <input type="submit"></form>

<?php
$dir = '/www/posts'; 
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir);

while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
    if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) 
    { 
        $last_dot_index = strrpos($file, ".");
        $withoutExt = substr($file, 0, $last_dot_index);
        echo "<a href='$withoutExt'>$withoutExt</a>"; 
        echo "<br>"; 
    }
}  
closedir($res); 
?>
```

But the above code gives the error : `Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in search.php on line 10`

I tried using the `!empty` argument like this:

```
<?php
$dir = '/www/posts'; 
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir);

if (!empty($res)) {
    while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
         if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) { 
             $last_dot_index = strrpos($file, ".");
             $withoutExt = substr($file, 0, $last_dot_index);
             echo "<a href='$withoutExt'>$withoutExt</a>"; 
             echo "<br>"; 
         }
         else {
             echo "";
         }
     }
}  
closedir($res); 
?>
```

But it still reflects the error.

Please help me get rid of this error.

Comment: please edit, comment and format/indent your code, as it's unreadable at the moment...

Comment: The php manual pages for string search functions use "haystack" and "needle" as the names of the parameters. Hence the strangely worded error messages when the string being searched for is empy (null).

Comment: For me, my error was `Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in ...` however it was actually the second parameter `haystack` which was empty. This was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check `$q` for emptiness. If it's empty - what's the point to search. There's even no need to run `opendir` if `$q` is empty.

```
if (!empty($q)) {
    $res = opendir($dir);
    while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
        // more codes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed the error:

```
$dir = 'c:/wamp64/www/posts'; 
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : ''; 
if (!empty($q)) {
$res = opendir($dir);
while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) { 
$last_dot_index = strrpos($file, ".");
$withoutExt = substr($file, 0, $last_dot_index);
echo "<a href='/blog.php?post=$withoutExt'>$withoutExt</a>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
}
}
closedir($res); 
}
else {
echo "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me. Before strpos, check if a variable has content:

```
/*   Example: 
 *   Suppose that the varible $x only has a value only in 
 *   some pages, but in some, it comes empty! 
 */

$p = strpos('hacker in action', "$x"); // <- This will produce a warning

// Minimal solution, php treats like boolean (true/false):
if( "$x" ){ $p = strpos('hacker in action', "$x"); ...

// Other ways:
if( "$x" != ''){
if( strlen("$x") > 0){
```